# Greater Than and Less Than in Column in Datagridview VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 3 columns in datagridview lets call it column `0`,`1` and `2` and here what it looks like.

[image]

My question is how can I make the column `0` turn to color orange when column `2` is greater than column `1`? For example the `Banana Catsup 4 kg` column `2` has a `5` and column `1` is greater than column `2` so in that case the column 0 will not turn to orange but in my example it turns to orange. Here is my code

```
Try
For i As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 3 Step -1
If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value > DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Then
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
End If
Next
Catch
End Try
```

When i observe my code it seems that my code works only on the first number. Please help me

TYSM

Comment: To which mehtod does this code belong to? Why loop from RowCount -1 to 3 and not 0 to RowCount -1 ? Have you tried `DataGridView1.Refresh()` after the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why complicate things when you can just do it like this?

```
    Try
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            If Val(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString) > Val(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString) Then
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Also, having an empty `catch` will give you trouble sooner or later.

Added `Val()` to cells to make sure it won't cause any problem when it's blank.

Comment: Your always there to help me sir TYSSM sir

Comment: Sorry for the late reply just finished my meeting

Comment: Just tried the code again sir but still the same output :(

Comment: No sir i tried it, don you think sir mysql column column type would affect them the columns with numbers are Decimal(10,2) in my table

Comment: I don't think that would likely be the case since it's already in your datagrid. Is that the real data showing in your image? Or the real question is, is that really the condition? If Cell(1) is greater than Cell(2)?

Comment: I think sir its working now i tried to adjust my other codes. TYSM for help always sir :D

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two string values. You first need to convert col1 and col2 values to INT then compare.

```
   Try
For i As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 3 Step -1
If CInt(Replace(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value,",","")) > CInt(Replace(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value,",","")) Then
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
End If
Next
Catch
End Try
```